# Popup menu goes out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-activity, android-appcompat

Popup menu on inflate goes out of the screen for this activity, works fine for other

[image]

Extending custom AppCompatActivity

Styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TransparentContextTranscition" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>

    <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Java code

```
holder.contextMenuView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.song_item_menu_album_inner_layout);
        }
});
```

Toolbar inflate menu works fine

[image]

Comment: have you use anchor ? also show java code.

Comment: updated @SohailZahid

Comment: Might sound silly, but this happened to me earlier today on an emulator, I ended up trying it on my device and it worked fine. did a clean and rebuild, issue resolved itself.

Comment: Great then answer your own question and tick mark.

Comment: Did clean project and rebuilded still not working.... @ziondreamt

Comment: Darn. Well I think you can force an offset with dropDownHorizontalOffset but that seems like a bad way to do it.

Comment: how can i achieve that ?? @ziondreamt

Comment: I couldn't find a good reference, but it's talked about quite a bit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449251/implement-pop-up-menu-with-margin

Comment: followed the step, got a unscrollable popup menu (Displaying only some part below the vertical more icon)  @ziondreamt

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Do you have update all the libraries and are you using all AppCompat tool?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 24, Physical device running 23.
Using custom AppCompatActivity... and all the libraries are updated...

Comment: instead of View Context pass Activity context (in your case Adapter context).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like I was using

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

my bad. FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, removes limits for the context menu. (That's the reason, the context menu going out of the screen), Hope that helps for someone

Comment: how to use FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS with popup menu, any solution?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I didnt find any solution for that. so i remove the FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS. Sorry for the late reply hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 9):

Use this in your code:

```
final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v, Gravity.RIGHT);
```

if it doesn't work then change the anchor view v. because it can set the position of the popup menu as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A simple yet-customizable Android drop-down menu. It supports Text with/without Icons, Separators, and even fully customized views

https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately popup menu does not follow the size of the view it is inside and goes off scope. I had the same problem before. And I know it is not the best solution but here it goes:

Create a **fake view** which is *transparent* to use *as anchor* to block the edge from exceeding.

However since it will be floating you cannot place it on the top or bottom side so careful on the height exceeding while trying this.

And by the way **do NOT forget** to set **`android:anyDensity="True/False"`**

Comment: How can i achieve it, can you provide me some steps

Comment: well I do not have your full layout so I don't know how your LinearLayouts and Floating items etc is located. But I can explain the main idea and you will get it after there. so the problem is that popup disobeys your edges so you have to replace it somewhere it will be okay on the look from outside right? you leave the popup there but you inflate it inside another View which is fake and located/floating) lets say a bit on the left side. so when the popupmenu inflates inside of it it will look perfectly in the right place. You cheat the outlooking of the design. good luck

Comment: again i am saying it is definetally not the best solution and it sounds like you give up on your coding talents and try to cheat. but isnt it all about? to find an easy way to do something right. following the thread if someone suggests a code related solution so I can also learn and fix my old app.

Comment: It may not work perfectly on large devices or different sdk (Correct me if am wrong)

Comment: not the best solution i said already. But with this idea the same, it is all about your designing. you can place a layout that looks like a popup menu and place choices inside of it with fixed size and have a scroolview inside of it also so it would be useful even with 100 choices.

Comment: That won't be an optimal solution, Thanks for the suggestion...
Maybe i will implement it with the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the popup menu to overlap with the anchor view.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29702608