# add margin on popup menu items

Tags: android, popup, android-theme

I am using the default pop menu with custom font(by overriding the default font), but it seems like the **items** have a little margin from bottom:

[image]

I think this problem is because of my font, but I like this font and I don't want to change it.

Do you have any suggestions about how can I add some margin from top on menu items?

Comment: Check this link i hope it will help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449251/implement-pop-up-menu-with-margin

Comment: Please post your code and xml design as well.....

Answer (score -1):

```
<style name="ucrop_popup_menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_11sdp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/graphit_regular</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/match_radius</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-16dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">@dimen/_16sdp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/ucrop_popup_menu</item>